# How to Load the RadGrid when fetching a huge data from the Table of the database using Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, radgrid, icriteria

I like to reduce the loading time when running the Default.aspx in the browser because it is fetching a huge data from the Table in the database.

When I use  criteria.SetMaxResults(200) the grid load only 200 datas but I should load all the data's in the RadGrid from the table in the database .When I use   criteria.SetFetchSize(200) it takes also a huge time to Load can anyone help me to find a solution for this.

Here is the code

```
    ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Ttable1));
    criteria.SetMaxResults(200);      
    IList result = criteria.List();
    if (result.Count > 0)
    {

        grid1.DataSource = result;
        grid1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        grid1.DataSource = new string[] { };
        grid1.DataBind();
    }
```

Here the Mapping is

```
  <class name="Ttable1" table="Ttable1" lazy="false"  mutable="true">
  <cache usage="read-only"/>
  <id name="ID" column="ID" >
  </id> 
  <property name="CustNumber" column="CustNumber" type="String" />
  <property name="CustName" column="CustName" type="String"/>
  <property name="PNo" column="PNor" type="String"/>
  <property name="ONo" column="ONo" type="String"/>
  <property name="Ln" column="Lns" type="String"/>
  <property name="Comments" column="Comments" type="String"/>
  <property name="size" column="size" type="String"/>
  <property name="Qty" column="Qty" type="String"/> 
  </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is the class
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;

```
   namespace Business.entities
      {
   public  class Ttable1
        {
    public virtual string displayobj { get; set; }
    public virtual Ttable1 TLQDataObj { get; set; }

    public virtual int?  ID  { get; set; }
    public virtual string CustNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string CustName  { get; set; }
    public virtual string PNo  { get; set; }
   public virtual string ONo  { get; set; }
 public virtual string Ln { get; set; }
 public virtual string Comments  { get; set; }
  public virtual string size  { get; set; }
  public virtual string Qty  { get; set; }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you show all data in grid with paging? if yes you can create custom paging for your grid by load 10 rows for every page you entered you can first retrieve paged data by using `query.SetFirstResult(firstrowinpage);` and `query.SetMaxResults(pageSize);` (HQL)
, and set Radgrid property `grid.AllowCustomPaging = true;` to allow custom paging and set VirtualItemCount to know grid how number of rows to allow paging.

```
grdItems.VirtualItemCount =numberofrows();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to tell what is wrong from what you have given us. We don't know your mappings, how many columns does the table have, nothing.

Problems could be caused either by:

- N+1 selects because all your associations are eager
- You have some column in the database with huge data (maybe some attachments or something)

You should also try to paginate your results.

You must debug NHibernate queries and see what is going on. You can do that either by using show_sql, by logging with some logger, or with some profiler like NHProf or even a SQL profiler.

You will probably see many queries executed because there is no lazy load enabled.

> EDIT:

If you have some columns in the table that you don't want to load unless you access them, you can set their property mapping with lazy=true, or you can map these columns with components and set these components as lazy=true. This way when you access these columns for the first time, additional queries will be performed.

Comment: I don't have any mapping in the table,it is only one table with around 20 columns with huge data.Please can you suggest me any coding to reduce the loading time

Comment: What is EDIT: please help me out

Comment: Denis I have to fetch around 100000 row data and the problem is created even when i use lazy="true"

Answer (score 1):

If you need to fetch data for display purposes you should create a light object from the table data.
In any case, if fetching speed is your only concern you could set the object as `mutable=false` and set the cache `<cache usage="read-only"/>`.

You could do this in code also:

```
ICriteria crit =  session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Ttable1));
crit.SetCacheable(true);
crit.SetCacheMode(CacheMode.Get);
crit.SetMaxResults(200);      
IList result = crit.List();
```

Mapping -

```
<class name="Ttable1" table="Ttable1" lazy="false"  mutable="false">
   <cache usage="read-only"/>
    <id name="ID">
       <column name="ID"/>
       <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="CustNumber" column="CustNumber" type="String" />
    <property name="CustName" column="CustName" type="String"/>
    <property name="PNo" column="PNor" type="String"/>
    <property name="ONo" column="ONo" type="String"/>
    <property name="Ln" column="Lns" type="String"/>
    <property name="Comments" column="Comments" type="String"/>
    <property name="size" column="size" type="String"/>
    <property name="Qty" column="Qty" type="String"/> 
  </class>
```

Comment: I can't access crit.SetCacheMode(CacheMode.ReadOnly) where The Readonly property is not coming

Comment: I can't able to fetch the bulk data I have done as per your instruction,please correct me

Comment: Mr Mush I have given the mapping in the Post please check it there is no mapping just fetching from the single table

Comment: What kind failure, exception, timeout?

Comment: General ADO exception Unhandled by the user This exception is thrown and also another exception System.OutOfMemory Exception

Comment: It is difficult to understand your problem. Please post your Ttable1 class and the surrounding code around your criteria. Also, change the mutable attribute in your mapping to false.

Comment: Mr Mush I also pasted the Icriteria surrounded codes and Class please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. I am getting this exception

Comment: I checked the code and it run perfectly. You should retrace your steps and re-check everything by my example. Do you make another call without SetMaxResults(). In which line does your exception occurs? What is your database, are you sure you're using the correct dialect?